# Replace pandas groupby and apply to increase performance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am using pandas groupby and apply to go from a DataFrame containing 150 million rows with the following columns:

```
Id  Created     Item    Stock   Price
1   2019-01-01  Item 1  200     10
1   2019-01-01  Item 2  100     15
2   2019-01-01  Item 1  200     10
```

To a list of 2,2 million records that looks like this:

```
[{
  "Id": 1,
  "Created": "2019-01-01",
  "Items": [
    {"Item":"Item 1", "Stock": 200, "Price": 10},
    {"Item":"Item 2", "Stock": 100, "Price": 5}
    ]
},
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Created": "2019-01-01",
  "Items": [
    {"Item":"Item 1", "Stock": 200, "Price": 10}
    ]
}]
```

Mainly using this line of code:

```
df.groupby(['Id', 'Created']).apply(lambda x: x[['Item', 'Stock', 'Price']].to_dict(orient='records'))
```

This takes quite some time and as I understand it, operations like this is heavy for pandas to perform. Is there a none-pandas way to accomplish the same but with greater performance?

**Edit**: The operation takes 55 minutes, I am using ScriptProcessor in AWS that lets me specify the amount of power I want.

**Edit 2**:
So with artonas solution I am getting close:
This is what I manage to produce now:

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {'1': defaultdict(list,
                         {'Id': '1',
                          'Created':'2019-01-01',
                          'Items': [{'Item': Item2, 'Stock': 100, 'Price': 15},
                                    {'Item': Item1, 'Stock': 200, 'Price': 10}]
                         })
            },
           {'2': defaultdict(list,
                         {'Id': '2',
                          'Created':'2019-01-01',
                          'Items': [{'Item': Item1, 'Stock': 200, 'Price': 10}]
                         })
            },
```

But how to go from the above, to this?

```
[{
  "Id": 1,
  "Created": "2019-01-01",
  "Items": [
    {"Item":"Item 1", "Stock": 200, "Price": 10},
    {"Item":"Item 2", "Stock": 100, "Price": 5}
    ]
},
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Created": "2019-01-01",
  "Items": [
    {"Item":"Item 1", "Stock": 200, "Price": 10}
    ]
}]
```

Basically Im only intrested in the part after "defaultdict(list, " for all records. I need to have it in a list that is not dependent on the Id as the key.

**Edit 3**: Last update containing the results for my production dataset.
With the accepted answer provided by artona I managed to go from **55** minutes to **7**(!) minutes. And without any major changes to my code. The solution provided by Phung Duy Phong took me from 55 minutes to 17, not to bad either.

Comment: could you share some  lines in your dataframe, with ur expected output

Comment: Yes, I updated the post.

Comment: If you are fishing for some sort of fast 'vectorized' `numpy` solution - no.  This isn't that kind of numerical array task. I can see doing this python dictionaries, but it still involves iterating through all rows.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what I am fishing for, just alternatives that might improve the performance. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Josef this list should be sorted (from lowest to highest id)?

Comment: And you removed "Created"? So it is necessary or not?

Comment: Created is still necessary, just left it out in the second example because I already managed to solve the "basic" structure and are adding created the same way I added "Id":1 . Sorting is not needed. I just want all the "Id"-objects directly in a regular list as shown in my original example above

Comment: See my latest edit for a clear example, again, no sorting needed.

Comment: Done, list is returned @Josef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use collections.defaultdict and itertuples. It iterates over row only one time.

```
In [105]: %timeit df.groupby(['Id', 'Created']).apply(lambda x: x[['Item', 'Stock', 'Price']].to_dict(orient='records'))
10.1 s ± 44.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [107]:from collections import defaultdict
     ...:def create_dict():
     ...:     dict_ids = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
     ...:     for row in df.itertuples():
     ...:          dict_ids[row.Id][row.Created].append({"Item": row.Item, "Stock": row.Stock, "Price": row.Price})
     ...:     list_of_dicts = [{"Id":key_id, "Created":key_created, "Items": values} for key_id, value_id in dict_ids.items() for key_created, values in value_id.items()]
     ...:     return list_of_dicts

In [108]: %timeit create_dict()
4.58 s ± 417 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Cool! Will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: This is way faster but I am not getting the results I am looking for...but maybe it's just some small adjustments. I am not getting fields names for row.Id, row.Created

Comment: Could you share the error trace? And is df.index created from ids?

Comment: And how do you want access the data - could you share the example? By index of item, like `dict_ids[1]["2019-01-01"]`?

Comment: I'am almost there after some minor changer...the only thing left is that I would like to access it only with dict_ids[0 (like an index)] instead of the Id itself. I will update my main post so you can see what I am now getting as output

Comment: See my Edit 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this now works. I will try it on the complete dataset and let you know the improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If the dataframe is cleanly sorted, meaning here that all rows for a same pair (`Id`, `Created`) are consecutive, you can simply iterate them. But as iterating a dataframe is expensive because pandas has to build a new Series per each row, I would directly iterate the underlying numpy arrays.

Code could be:

```
records = []
Id = None

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Id'].values[i] != Id or df['Created'].values[i] != created:
        items = []
        Id = df['Id'].values[i]
        created = df['Created'].values[i]
        records.append({'Id': Id, 'Created': created,
                'Items': items})

    items.append({x: df[x].values[i]
              for x in ['Item', 'Stock', 'Price']})
```

If data is not initially sorted, you could try to sort the dataframe with pandas and then use above code

Comment: I tried this one earlier but don't think is fast enough. Thanks

Comment: I could test it on my system at 30 seconds for 1,5 millions rows. I have not enough memory to test with 150 millions...

Comment: Yeah so if 1,5 takes 30 seconds one could estimate 150 taking approx. 3000 seconds, or 50 minutes. Not good enough. Artonas solution will beat this.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
df['Items'] = df.loc[:, ['X', 'Y', 'Z']].to_dict(orient='records')
df.groupby(['ID', 'CREATED'])['Items'].apply(list).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: I will try it and get back to you with the results.

Comment: I test it with around 1m records, it definitely much faster on my computer, but dont know about memory usage on your computer, since it duplicate data in 3 columns, careful for your memory usage I think

Comment: That was almost three times as fast! (removed faulty edit)

Comment: those level_0 field maybe at `reset_index`, you might want to look into that

Comment: I fixed it, it was another line that was not supposed to be there.

Comment: with my dummy dataset it is slower:
11.4 s ± 273 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: That's weird, when I tried it on my set it went from 24 seconds to 7 seconds. I will try it on the complete dataset that took 55 minutes with the "old" way. Then I will try your proposal as well.

Comment: So I went from 55 minutes to 17 minutes with this solution, that is good considering the small change that was needed. I will try to figure out the solution provided by artona before accepting.